# Reading from a stream of go channels

Tags: go, channel

I was trying to understand the following piece of code that reads from a channel of channels. I am having some difficulties wrapping my head around the idea.

```golang
    bridge := func(done <-chan interface{}, chanStream <-chan <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
        outStream := make(chan interface{})
        go func() {
            defer close(outStream)
            for {
                var stream <-chan interface{}
                select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case maybeSteram, ok := <-chanStream:
                    if ok == false {
                        return
                    }
                    stream = maybeSteram
                }
                for c := range orDone(done, stream) {
                    select {
                    case outStream <- c:
                    case <-done:  // Why we are selection from the done channel here?
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
        return outStream
    }
```

The `orDone` function:

```golang
    orDone := func(done <-chan interface{}, inStream <-chan interface{}) <-chan interface{} {
        outStream := make(chan interface{})
        go func() {
            defer close(outStream)
            for {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case v, ok := <-inStream:
                    if ok == false {
                        return
                    }
                    select {
                    case outStream <- v:
                    case <-done:  // Again why we are only reading from this channel? Shouldn't we return from here?
                        // Why we are not retuening from here?
                    }
                }
            }
        }()
        return outStream
    }
```

As mentioned in the comment, I need some help to understand why we are selecting in the `for c := range orDone(donem, stream)`. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

I took the code from the book `concurrency in go`. The full code can be found here: https://github.com/kat-co/concurrency-in-go-src/blob/master/concurrency-patterns-in-go/the-bridge-channel/fig-bridge-channel.go

Comment: Could you perhaps references where you found this? (a link)

Comment: I took the reference from a book named `concurrency in go`. the code can be found here: https://github.com/kat-co/concurrency-in-go-src/blob/master/concurrency-patterns-in-go/the-bridge-channel/fig-bridge-channel.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the select is done to avoid blocking — if the reader isn't reading from our output channel, the write might block (maybe even forever), but we want the goroutine to terminate when the `done` channel is closed, without waiting for anything else. By using the `select`, it will wait until *either* thing happens, and then continue, instead of waiting indefinitely for the write to complete before checking `done`.

As for the other question, "why are we not returning here?": well, we *could*. But we don't *have to*, because a closed channel remains readable forever (producing an unlimited number of zero values) once it's been closed. So it's okay to do nothing in those "bottom" `selects`; if `done` was in fact closed we will go back up to the top of the loop and hit the `case <-done: return` there. I suppose it's a matter of style. I probably would have written the `return` myself, but the author of this sample may have wanted to avoid handling the same condition in two places. As long as it's just `return` it doesn't really matter, but if you wanted to do some *additional* action on `done`, that behavior would have to be updated in two places if the bottom select returns, but only in one place if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Fist I will explain the usage of done channel. It's a common pattern followed in many concurrency related package implementation in Go. Done channels purpose is to denote the end of computation or more like a stop signal. Usually done channel will be listened by many go-routines or multiple places in code flow. One such example is Done channel in [Go's builtin "context" package](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context). Since Go doesn't have anything like broadcast ie., to signal all listeners of a channel (expecting this feature is not a good idea too), people just close the channel and all listeners will receive nil value. In your case, since the second select statement is in the end of for block, the code owner might have decided to just continue the loop so that on next iteration, the first select statement which listens on done channel will return from the function.